# How to convert `[[Either String c]]` into `Either String [[c]]`?

Tags: haskell

Say I have two functions:

```
b2c :: B -> Either String C
a2bs :: A -> [[B]]
```

How to make the following `a2cs` function using `b2c` and `a2bs` such that if there is any Left value in the `[[Either String c]]` then `Either String [[c]]` should be a Left value?

```
a2cs :: A -> Either String [[C]]
```

Comment: When you say the type of `b2c` is `b -> Either String c`, it's not really `b` is it? It's some other more concrete type, not a type var... same for the other function, right?

Comment: Yes, a, b, c in the type signatures are all concrete types.

Comment: Also when you say the if there's any `Left` value then `Either String [[c]]` should be a `Left` value, which should it be? What should be on `Left`? Concatenated strings?

Comment: @LeoZhang Consider writing them with uppercase letters in the types, then.  Lowercase-starting identifers are reserved for type variables.

Comment: `sequence` function from `Control.Monad` package isn't the think your are looking for?

Comment: And on more question, can't your problem be reduced first to a function with type `[Either String c] -> Either String [c]`?

Comment: Simple solution will be `getCompose <$> sequence (Compose [[Right 10, Right 20]])`
Or `f = fmap getCompose . sequence . Compose`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`sequence`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BY5WE66YKcU) for this, but it's not a single step.  It commutes one pair of layers of type constructors, but you need to move the `Either String` constructor out two type layers.  Well, our old friend `map` comes in handy.

```
foo1 :: [[Either String c]] -> [Either String [c]]
foo1 = map sequence
```

And then to go the rest of the way:

```
foo2 :: [Either String [c]] -> Either String [[c]]
foo2 = sequence
```

If you want to be more compact, you can just put it all together with function composition:  `sequence . map sequence :: [[Either String c]] -> Either String [[c]]`

Answer (score 6):

I would write this:

```
a2cs = traverse (traverse b2c) . a2bs
```

Although this doesn't use exactly your proposed implementation strategy of first producing a `[[Either String C]]` and then flattening that to `Either String [[C]]`, it has the advantage that it requires only one pass over the nested lists rather than the two required by your strategy.

Answer (score 3):

first convert your `[[Either String c]]` into `[Either String [c]]` then convert it to `Either String [[c]]` as follows:

```
func = sequence . map sequence

func [[Right 1, Right 2], [Left "a"]]
> Left "a"

func [[Right 1, Right 2], [Right 3]]
> Right [[1,2][3]]
```